# Why use HTML entities instead of just putting Unicode characters in HTML?

Tags: html, content-encoding, compatibility, unicode

Let's say I want to put a non-bland character in an HTML file; for instance, '→'. Is there any reason why I should enter it as '&rarr;' instead of just putting '→' in the HTML file? Assume my HTML file is encoded & transmitted in some Unicode format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those two final statements are big assumptions.

For example, we have a web app that uses AJAX to its literal meaning - we use it for loading XML documents on the fly. If the XML document does not have the correct `content-encoding` header (or is lacking one at all), then any unicode characters (smartquotes, long dashes, even some special whitespace and the word `Café`) makes Internet Explorer fall on its arse every single time. The AJAX request just fails and fires off a javascript error.

However, if we do a server-side replace of all the unicode characters with their HTML entities, everything works just fine.

Of course, if your file has the correct content-headers then this shouldn't be a problem for any modern browser.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the excellent accepted answer: on the whole, ASCII files are much more portable across various editors.

Answer (score 0):

> However, if we do a server-side replace of all the unicode characters with their HTML entities, everything works just fine.

This assumes all characters can be replaced with HTML-entities, which they can’t. Use the correct headers and spot these issues (using the wrong header) early, instead of being confused when they occur later.

Comment: Actually, *every* unicode character has an appropriate HTML entity.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I was thinking of the named entities. :)